# How to modify a partitioning layout (which may involve converting a primary partition to an extended one)

Tags: partition

I am having trouble thinking through how I can achieve my partitioning goals.

Now my partitions are:

- sda1 (winA) (primary)
- sda2 (winB) (primary)
- sda3 (/ for linux) (primary)

What I want to migrate into is (obviously partition numbers need not be exactly like that)

- sda1 (winA) (primary)
- sda2 (winB) (primary)
- sda3 (/boot) (primary)
- sda4 - extended which will contain

  - sda5 (/home)
  - sda6 (/)
  - sda7 (swap)

One way I have thought is:

1. Create a new primary partition for /boot and split it from the root partition into the new one. It shouldn't be too hard. Then the disk will have 4 primary partitions.
2. Somehow convert the root ubuntu partition from primary to extended.
3. Split that last partition in 3 extended partitions (root, /home, swap) and split the contents there.

I am obviously stuck on the 2nd part.

Another way could be (maybe easier):

1. Create an extended partition (or two)
2. Split /home there
3. Somehow move everything except /boot to the extended partition. This way /boot will stay on the primary partition that exists now, and will be shrunk as needed, and everything else will end up to the extended partitions.

This may sound better, but I'm not too sure how to do the 3rd part and I'd like some feedback.

Some details: The disk is almost empty, so I have space to move things around in it, shrink the linux partition etc. I don't want to touch the windows partitions in any way. Reinstallation is not an option. Also using a different partitioning scheme with fewer partitions is not an option (for example not having a separate /boot)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second solution (create/split/move) seems good.
I tried to come up with some short guide, but **be careful**. Maybe wait for other answers/comments. **Note:** if you are not familiar with command line maybe, this guide is probably not what you are looking for.

**A.** Create the extended partition (`sda4`) for `/home`, `/` and `swap` as you described. Reboot to reload the partition table.

**B.** Format the new partitions with the chosen filesystem type, e.g. `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda5` and `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6`. Format the `swap` with `mkswap /dev/sda7`.

**C.** Then, in a first time you can safely copy the content from the old `sda3` to the new partitions using `cp -a`. Something like:

```
mkdir /mnt/{oldslash,newhome,newslash}
mount --bind / /mnt/oldslash  #mounted without submount points like /dev /proc
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/newhome
mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/newslash
cp -a /mnt/oldslash/* /mnt/newslash
rm -rf /mnt/newslash/home/*   # homes will be copied to newhome
cp -a /home/* /mnt/newhome
```

**D.** Verify that the layouts in `newslash` and `newhome` are ok. Check you don't have `.*` files in `/` and `/home`, or copy them to their respective targets. Then:

```
umount /mnt/oldslash
umount /mnt/newslash
umount /mnt/newhome
```

**E.** Then modify `/etc/fstab` considering the new partitions devices for `/`, `/home` (and swap).

**F.** Reboot and hope for the best. (Be sure to have some emergency live cd to repair your `/etc/fstab` in case something goes wrong and the system won't boot.)

**G.** Then, if everything goes as expected, you can remove everything except `/boot` from your boot (`sda3`) partition.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything worked fine in the end. I only had a bit trouble with moving and resizing /boot because grub broke, but all that was needed was a reinstall of grub.